# Insert to second place in a vector omnet++

Tags: function, vector, insert, omnet++

I want to push a element into the second place in a vector (omnet++),
and if the vector is full i want to drop the most recent element, 
is there any function for the job?

Comment: Are you looking for a built-in function, a function from a library, or something you want to write yourself?

Comment: Better to use a built-in function. but if there is no such function i need to write something myself

Answer (score 0):

For inserting:

```
vector<int> myvector;
myvector.insert ( myvector.begin() + 1 , 100 );
```

For checking:

```
if (myvector.size() == SIZE) {   
    myvector.pop_back();
}
```

Hope it helps.